# Trying to format dates column from chr to Date but returning NA

Tags: r, date

I've imported and xlsx file and I have a column of dates as characters:

```
Jan 08
Feb 08
Mar 08
Apr 08
```

etc...

I want to convert this column into dates. I've tried some suggestions I've seen on other threads but I can't get it to not return NA

Here's the latest attempt:

```
dates <- format(as.Date(MonthlyUKFigures$Date,format="%b-%y"),format="%b-%y")
```

Comment: I think this will anser your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122645/lubridate-how-to-parse-month-year

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `lubridate` package:

```
my("Jan 08")
[1] "2008-01-01"
```